# How to avoid using foreach loop to get the filelist for different reason

Tags: c#

Here what am trying to do:

1. I have a remote server (e.g:svr01,svr02,svr03). Using `GetFileList` to read the directory get all the files and match with the file name I have then copy to my local drive.
2. If any files matched then am adding them to an XML file also.

I was trying to do like below

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var getfiles = new fileshare.Program();

        string realname = "*main*";
        string Location = "SVR01";
        bool anymatch = false;
         foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
        {anymatch=true;}
         if (anymatch == true)
         { baseMeta(); }
        foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
        {getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName); }

        }

    private FileInfo[] GetFileList(string pattern,string Location)
    {

        try
        {
            switch (Location)
            {
                case "SVR01":
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\SVR01\Dev");
                        return di.GetFiles(pattern);
                    }
                case "SVR02":
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\SVR02\Dev");
                        return di.GetFiles(pattern);
                    }
                case "SVR03":
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\SVR03\Prod");
                        return di.GetFiles(pattern);
                    }
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        return null;
        }

    }
    private void copytolocal(string filename)
    {
        string nameonly = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        File.Copy(filename,Path.Combine(@"c:\",nameonly),true);

    }

    private void baseMeta()
    {

                XmlWriter xmlWrite = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\basexml");
                xmlWrite.WriteStartElement("job");
                xmlWrite.WriteElementString("Name", "test");
                xmlWrite.WriteElementString("time", DateTime);
                xmlWrite.Close();

    }
}
```

but this piece of code worries me because am doing the same process two times, any one please guide me how to avoid this.

```
 foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
 {
     anymatch=true;}
     if (anymatch == true)
     { 
          baseMeta(); 
     }
     foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
     {
         getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName); 
     }
 }
```

Even am trying to find out if it match anyfile then i quit the first foreach loop generate the **basemeta()** then goes to next foreach loop to do the rest of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ you should be able to easily change your posted code into:

```
var getfiles = new fileshare.Program();
string realname = "*main*";
string Location = "SVR01";
var fileList = getFiles.GetFileList(realname, Location);
var anymatch = fileList.Any();

if (anymatch) // Or possibly `if (fileList.Any())` if anymatch isn't 
              // really used anywhere else
    baseMeta();

foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
    getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName);
```

You'll get the greatest benefit by replacing your `GetFileList` method with:

```
private IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFileList(string pattern,string Location)
{
    string directory = string.Empty;

    switch (Location)
    {
        case "SVR01":
            directory = @"\\SVR01\Dev";
        break;

        case "SVR02":
            directory = @"\\SVR02\Dev";
        break;

        case "SVR03":
            directory = @"\\SVR03\Prod");
        break;

        default: 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    }

    DirectoryInfo di = null;
    try
    {
        di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        yield break;
    }

    foreach(var fi in di.EnumerateFiles(pattern))
        yield return fi;
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for the great code,honestly i couldn't understand how it works,am just wondering where you use "pattern" in the code.Greatly appreciated if you explain little bit.

Comment: I didn't include those variables in my code sample because they should have been implied by their usage (in the first snippet) they've been added now. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Am using your code to get the files from the directory but i noticed one thing its not checking the sub directories .for e.g the directory path "@"\\SVR02\Dev" ,i have sub dir's in the same path but this process doesn't check the sub dir ? any suggestion what i suppose to change to check the sub dir also ?thanks in advance

Comment: @Usher - If you want to get files from subdirectories, you should use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343.aspx) overload of `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: thanks you so much. I was trying in directory info to search sub dirs but it throws exception. Thanks again to enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var files = getfiles.GetFileList(realname, Location);
if (files.Length > 0)  
{ 
    baseMeta(); 
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Create method to check the file existence and do all in single loop. 
>   your statement is not much clear that when you will copy or not..  use
>   your condition on which you want to copy or create xml entry..

What is your AnyMatch?? If you want to check that Is there any file then use

```
var fileList = getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location);

  if( fileList.Count() > 0)
  {
    baseMeta();      
  }
  foreach (var file in fileList)
  {

      // copy the file if match does not exist..
      getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName);
  }
```

*But Foreach loop through collection if it have any item. so you need not to care about the count of the files..*

If you want to do entry on every copy as per your code then why you need to check anyMatch etc. It will create entry on every file copy.

```
foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
{
  baseMeta();      
  // copy the file 
  getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName);
}
```